# Membership PayPal Renewal Redirect Too Many Times

Tags: wordpress, civimember, paypal, 4.7.14

CiviCRM 4.7.15 WordPress

Since January clients have been getting:

> The website.org page isn't working
>   website.org redirected you too many
>   times

Seems it only happens to PayPal customers renewing their membership. Those signing up for conferences do not encounter this problem. The error appears instead of the confirmation page.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Could be related to [CRM-17676](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/projects/CRM/issues/CRM-17676)?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've got a misconfiguration in your web server (Apache/nginx/etc.) configuration in your "rewrite rules".  You'll need to involve your web server administrator.

The easiest way to spot this is:

- Go to the affected page.
- Press "F12" to bring up Developer tools.
- Select the "Network" tab.
- Submit the form that causes the problem.

At this point, your Network tab should fill up with URLs it's trying to access.  My guess is it looks something like:

```
http://mysite.org/something/contribute
http://mysite.org/something/something/contribute
http://mysite.org/something/something/something/contribute
http://mysite.org/something/something/something/something/contribute
```

etc.

Compare that to your rewrite rules (if using Apache, be sure to check .htaccess files), looking for the "something" in your configuration.  That's the rule that's causing the issue.